# Matching any number except 1 with Regex

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression now that matches any number:

```
/(\d)/
```

Now I'd like to modify it to not pick up 1, so it should capture 238, 12, 41, but not 1.

Does anyone see a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming Negative Lookahead is supported you could do:

```
^(?!1$)\d+$
```

Or simply use the alternation operator in context placing what you want to exclude on the left-hand side, and place what you want to match in a capturing group on the right-hand side.

```
\b1\b|(\d+)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nX9aI9/3)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression

```
\b[02-9]\b|\d{2,}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/(?!1$)\d+/`
Try this code in PHP:

```
   $a ="1";
   $b ="2";
   $reg = "/(?!1$)\d+/";
   echo preg_match($reg, $a);
   echo preg_match($reg, $b);
```

Comment: That would also exclude 12